# How to pass an array to a powershell script in TFS build?

Tags: powershell, tfsbuild

I'm running TFS 2013 and have a "pre-build" powershell script which accepts an array of strings and a string as parameters. My question is how do I pass an array of strings *and* an individual string to the script?

It's easy enough to do that from straight powershell:

```
function Do-Something() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [string[]] $files,
        [string]$pathToSearch
    )

    Clear-Host

    foreach ($file in $files) {
        Write-Host "File path: $file"
    }
}

Do-Something -files:("one", "two", "three") -pathToSearch:"pathToSearch!!"
```

However, it doesn't seem to be that easy via TFS:

In the pre-build script arguments I have the following:

```
"123.txt", "C:\"
```

All of these get put into the array parameter. I tried doing something like this:

```
-files:("123.txt") -pathToSearch: "C:\"
```

but then it seems that the first parameter value is ("123.txt") instead of just "123.txt".

Comment: Check this article http://get-powershell.com/post/2008/02/07/Powershell-function-New-Array.aspx

Comment: How is your script getting invoked?  Is this from a VS pre-build event or are you using MSBuild's Exec task?

Comment: @KeithHill it is being invoked via the pre-build script portion of TFS 2013 build: http://blog.nwcadence.com/whats-new-in-tfs-2013-team-builds-are-able-to-run-in-powershell/

Comment: We're still on TFS 2012 but if it is like the InvokeProcess activity, try this `powershell.exe -Command "& {& 'c:\path\to\script.ps1' -files 123.txt,C:\ -pathToSearch c:\}"`

Comment: How did you get your pre-build to accept an array of strings as arguments?

Comment: Do the colons have any function?  Tried `-Files "123.txt","456.txt" -pathToSearch "C:\"` ?

OR

`$files = "123.txt","456.txt";
$path = "c:\";
Do-Something -files $files -pathToSearch $path`